# Why is EmployeeRoomDatabase::class.java showing error in the class that is written for RoomDatabase?

Tags: android, android-room

So I am setting up the Room Database and it's entity class and Dao Interface, so when I am write the the class for Room Database, I am getting following error.

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room

@Database(entities = [(Employee::class)], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class EmployeeRoomDatabase {

    abstract fun employeeDao(): EmployeeDao

    companion object {
        /*The value of a volatile variable will never be cached, and all writes and reads will be done to and from the main memory.
        This helps make sure the value of INSTANCE is always up-to-date and the same for all execution threads.
        It means that changes made by one thread to INSTANCE are visible to all other threads immediately.*/
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: EmployeeRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): EmployeeRoomDatabase {
            // only one thread of execution at a time can enter this block of code
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE

                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        EmployeeRoomDatabase::class.java,
                        "employee_database"
                    ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()

                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Whats the exact error?

Comment: I solved the error, I wasn't inheriting RoomDatabase  for 'abstract class EmployeeRoomDatabase ' , so after I inherited it with RoomDatabase, the error the line where EmployeeRoomDatabase::class.java was went away